# javascript/css transform + z-index issue with google chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, webkit, transform

some issue with google chrome, center image [must be on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz1yt.png), but they don't.

Please try following code to repeat this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

function big_image(myelem) {
myelem.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(2.0)';
myelem.style.zIndex = '99';
}


function orig_image(myelem) {
myelem.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1.0)';
myelem.style.zIndex = 'auto';
}

</script>


</head>
<body>

<img src="http://www.pewforum.org/files/2015/10/PF_15.10.05_PostPapal_promo260x260.jpg" onmouseover="big_image(this);" onmouseout="orig_image(this);">

<img src="http://www.pewforum.org/files/2015/10/PF_15.10.05_PostPapal_promo260x260.jpg" onmouseover="big_image(this);" onmouseout="orig_image(this);">

<img src="http://www.pewforum.org/files/2015/10/PF_15.10.05_PostPapal_promo260x260.jpg" onmouseover="big_image(this);" onmouseout="orig_image(this);">

</body>
</html>
```

How to fix / overcome it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug to do with z-index and transform properties.

The best way to avoid it, will be to reset transform property `onmouseout`:

```
function big_image(myelem) {
    myelem.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(2.0)';
    myelem.style.zIndex = '2';
}


function orig_image(myelem) {
    myelem.style.webkitTransform = 'none';
    myelem.style.zIndex = '1';
}
```

Tested and works as expected on Chrome/Opera.